# Error using window.location.href

Tags: javascript

I am working through the book: Beginning Javascript and using Chrome as my browser.

The line window.location.href is used in the following code:

```
<! DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Ch 8</title>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function window_onload()
{
    alert("The name of the lower frame's window object is "
    + window.name);
    alert("The location of the lowerWindow's parent is "
    + window.parent.location.href);
}
</script>
```

Lower Frame

The parent is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC *-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Ch. 8</title>
</head>
<frameset row = "50%, *" id = "topWindow">
    <frame name = "upperWindow" src = "ch08_examp1_upper.htm" />
    <frame name = "lowerWindow" src = "ch08_examp1_lower.htm" />
</frameset>
</hmtl>
```

This throws the following error:
"Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match."

The file is saved in the same directory as the parent file. Is there something blatantly wrong with what I have done?

Comment: Base on the error message your "child location" is different from "parent location". Basically is different URL or Port number

Comment: the reason this error is occurring is due to some other part of your HTML or JavaScript, which is unfortunately not listed here for review.

Comment: I have them side by side in my directory. (They both have the position C:\Users\Saralyn\Documents in my computer.)  Should I be doing something else?

Comment: Does the book talk about using a local web server? I remember running into something similar that was solved by visiting the pages with a local server and not by the filesystem (File > Open)

Comment: I am using only local files, I assume that is the same as using a local server? Sorry I only started coding a month ago... all of this is so new!

Comment: @Saralyn If the book doesn't mention servers, there must be another way to get your pages to work. I meant using software like Apache, or the packaged versions XAMPP, WAMP or EasyPHP. But, I think it will be overkill. I would only consider installing these if you are interested in building a more full-featured site down the road. These packages include a database and PHP, in this use case as a server-side language.

Comment: FYI, frames are obsoleted in html5. So i want to recommend you to use updated book :)

Comment: @Ryan Thank you so much. You just saved me a bunch of time.